# GeoGratis API, 'OR'ing categories in a single request

Tags: request, geogratis

I am a developer trying to work with the GeoGratis web API, provided here: http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en

I want to make a request like this:

```
http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/-/OR/(urn:iso:type)map/(urn:gc:subject)climate
```

but no response is given. This request does work:

```
http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/-/AND/(urn:iso:type)map/(urn:gc:subject)climate
```

The difference between the two requests is the use of 'OR' in the first and 'AND' in the second.

I would like to be able to make one request that returns results from multiple groups, currently it looks like I have to make multiple requests and collate the results manually.

Comment: PS. If someone can add the tag 'geogratis', that would be useful, I don't have enough reputation to be able to do this.

Comment: got two 'search' items returned when like http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/-/%28urn:iso:type%29map?q=islands%20climate

Comment: @Mapperz, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are suggesting. I realize that I could make two separate searches, and then join the results myself - but I am wondering if the API will do this for me.

Comment: The one search is getting 'islands' and 'climate' topics returned, it does not seem that OR does not work.

Comment: The catagories that I am trying to join are: '(urn:gc:subject)climate' and '(urn:iso:type)map'. These are from the set of topic tags listed here: http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/$categories

Answer (score 1):

In theory, requests with a leading OR should work, but in practice, they perform very poorly.  We recommend you use a leading 'AND' (the default) operator, as the common use case is to filter the feed.

Comment: Hello! welcome to GIS.Stackexchange! Generally the more detail your answer has, the more it will be upvoted. Hence I suggest that you expand your answer with more details if possible.

Comment: Does this mean that we should assume the use of OR is not supported? My current work-around is to make separate requests for each of the four categories I am interested in. This works acceptably, but it would be better if I could get items from all four categories in a single request.